# Am I trying to use Ninject incorrectly, or am I missing something obvious?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject-2

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC web application.  I wanted to build a nice data layer that abstracted everything.  So like a good data layer, the controller wouldn't talk directly to the database.

Now, of course, inside the data layer there's a lot of things that WILL need to talk to the database.  I'd like all these objects to use the same data context (this is using Linq2SQL, but not thinking that should matter much.)  So yes, this is sounding a lot like a repository or unit of work pattern.  It kind of is, except I'm mostly just implementing the unit of work part.

Now, my problem is how do i get the data context to all the classes that need it?  I had thought Ninject could just inject it where I need.  And it does, IF the object I'm constructing only has one parameter in it's constructor.

So this seems to work well:

```
public class InjectedFoo
{
     InjectedFoo(IInjectable ii) {/*stuff*/}
}
```

This, however, gives me compiler errors:

```
public class InjectedFoo
{
     InjectedFoo(Object stuff, IInjectable ii) {/*stuff*/}
}
```

Which, yes, makes perfect sense.  After all the compiler doesn't know that Ninject will be creating that second parameter.  But at the same time, with only one parameter Ninject figures it out... which kind of seems like the point.  So how can I do it with those two parameters?

Now, let's up the ante a bit:

```
public static class FooFactory
{
    public static MakeFoo(int fooID, IInjectable ii)
    {
    }
}
```

So now I want a class to use the existing data context without ever actually being instantiated.  And I need to pass it the ID of the object I want.  So of course I have the same problem with the second parameter not being passed in so the compiler complains, but I can't even use property injection because I can't have a non-static property.  (I know I could use a static property, but I don't know that it would be safe.)

So I feel like I'm either using Ninject incorrectly, or just plain missing something that handles this.  Unfortunately all the documentation and examples seem to focus on very simple 1-argument constructors...

Comment: Hint: did you try to pass two `IInjectable`s as parameters? Or `IInjectable` and `IAnotherInjectable`? If yes, how's that different from your examples?

Comment: I'm probably terrible enough at Ninject that I need more of a hint.  What I'm realizing in trying to answer your question is that I'm not actually directly calling constructors anywhere... it's only being injected in the controller constructors which aren't called by me.

Comment: How are you creating instances?

Comment: Instances of what?  The controllers?  I'm not, MVC is doing that for me somewhere... If you mean the IInjectable it's in a Ninject module just using Bind.To.InRequestScope

Comment: The thing is that to be able to resolve something, an IoC container has to have the "binding" which is mapping between types and their representations. A representation of an interface or an abstract class can be a concrete class. A representation of a type (even a value type) can be a value. This means that if you want the container to resolve `int`s or `object`s you have to first **register** them in your container ("kernel" in NInject language).

Comment: I don't want the container to resolve int or object.  I want to pass in the first argument, and have Ninject resolve the second...